# Python Pandas text splitting

Tags: python, string, pandas

I got a function to save pandas dataframe to png format.It works fine but the first column of the dataframe is includes a lot of text, it does not seems good in png

```
# the data param is the dataframe
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=5.0, row_height=1, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):

    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')


    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)


    for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
    #saving figure
    ax.get_figure().savefig('foo.png')
```

What I want to do is, I want to make split the first column which includes a lot of text to next line like by 50 character.How can I make it.

My dataframe.The text rows I want to split to 2 line ('\n').
Just want to make it readable

```
def timeline_df(data):
    id_list=[data.id for d in data]
    data_set=pd.DataFrame(id_list,columns=["id"])


    data_set["text"]=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
    data_set["count1"]=[tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    data_set["count2"]=[tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    data_set["source"]=[tweet.source for tweet in tweets]

    return data_set
```

The text colums data like

```
"some text, some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text some textsome text➤ https://some textsome textsome textsome text"

What I want is
"some text, some textsome textsome textsome textsome 
textsome text some textsome text➤
 https://some textsome textsome textsome text"
```

Comment: It would *really* help if you could provide a minimal copy-pastable version of your code, *including some (sample) data*. Please read and understand [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added sample data